I can't change a texture only for the local player
I am trying to change a part's texture just for the local player, but it doesn't work at all.
I've tried to change it trough a localscript, which I put inside the model in which the part is contained, but nothing happens at all. This is a problem of the localscript, as this same code works in a server script.
Any help is welcomed

By default, LocalScripts will not run under workspace (unless in the character), to resolve this problem you can either:

Move the LocalScript into StarterPlayerScripts
Convert the LocalScript into a Script and change the RunContext to Client

See: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/live-script-runcontext/1938784
